# jQuery UI Design Pattern Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm reading through the jQuery UI source code (ui-dialog specifically), I see this pattern repeated many times:

```
    var self = this,
        options = self.options,
        uiDialog = self.uiDialog;
```

What's the reasoning behind this pattern of, `var self = this, something, something else`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning `self` helps with scope problems — the meaning of `this` might change throughout the script, `self` will always stay the reference to the instance. Common other forms are `that` and `base`.

The comma allows to write `var` only once in front of the variable definitions.

```
var self = this,
    options = self.options,
    uiDialog = self.uiDialog;
```

is the same as

```
var self = this;
var options = self.options;
var uiDialog = self.uiDialog;
```

Comment: "The comma allows to write var only once in front of the variable definitions."  Ahh, that's what that's about.

Answer (score 8):

it's just **caching** variables && obect propertys. This in general is considered as very good practice since object lookups come with a cost.

```
window.href
```

takes much more time than

```
var myhref = window.href;
myhref;
```

Of course you need to make the expensive call once, but all further calls to the cached variable are much much faster.

Another reason for using this pattern is to cache `DOM node references` for pretty much the same reasons. Accessing the `DOM` is one of the most expensive things you can do in Javascript (in a browser). So by caching references you just boost your code.